# How do I exclude an IOS 8 app extension from a build?

Tags: ios8, ios8-extension, ios8-today-widget

I am building two versions of my app from the same code base, one for IOS 7/8 and one that is IOS 8 only. I would like to exclude the extension from the 7/8 applications but include it in the IOS 8 version. I've looked in the info.plist, the build phases and the schemes for the apps and the extension and have found no references to either.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple. Any hints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I've looked in the info.plist, the **build phases** and the schemes for the apps and the extension and have found no references to either.

Look again? The setting that controls whether an app includes an extension is in the build phases for the app. By default it's called "Embed App Extensions", but you can rename it to whatever you like.

[image: Embed App Extensions build phase]

Select the extension(s) and click the "-" button at the bottom.

You probably also want to remove the extension from the target dependencies for the 7/8 app.